# Discretizing second order PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, discrete-calculus

I am atempting to discretize the following two PDEs:

$$\ \frac\partial{\partial x}(T\frac{\partial h}{\partial x})=-N+S\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\tau\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x})$$

$$\ \frac\partial{\partial x}(\tau\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial x})=n\frac{\partial \zeta}{\partial t}-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac\tau v \frac{\partial h}{\partial x})$$

Where $T,\tau,v,N,S$ are constants and do not depend on $x$ or $t$.

My intention is to produce marching equations which I can use to step through time. i.e. find the values of $h$ and $\zeta$ at time $t+k\Delta t$. 
All inputs would be discrete points.

I tried using finite difference methods and got the following two equations:
$$h_i^{k+1}=C_Th_{i+1}^k+(1-2C_T)h_{i}^k+C_Th_{i-1}^k+\frac{\Delta tN}{S}+C_{\tau}\zeta_{i+1}^k-2C_{\tau}\zeta_{i}^k+C_{\tau}\zeta_{i-1}^k$$ 
$$\zeta_i^{k+1}=D_{\tau}\zeta_{i+1}^k+(1-2D_{\tau})\zeta_{i}^k+D_{\tau}\zeta_{i-1}^k+\frac{D_{\tau}}{v}\zeta_{i+1}^k+\frac{D_{\tau}}{v}\zeta_{i}^k+\frac{D_{\tau}}{v}\zeta_{i-1}^k$$

Where $C_T=\frac{\Delta tT}{S\Delta x^2}, C_{\tau}=\frac{\Delta t\tau}{S\Delta x^2}, D_{\tau}=\frac{\Delta t\tau}{n\Delta x^2}$

Does this look correct?

Comment: "Finite Difference Methods" could offer an approach.

Comment: @CraigHicks Thank you. I gave it a shot. I edited the question to include what I got. Does it look correct?

Comment: So you converted by plugging in the discrete finite differences and then solved the simultaneous equations for your variables using an algebraic solver (e.g. free Mathematica online, or whatever you have)?

Comment: First I put the time derivative on one side of the equation, then I plugged in the discrete finite differences for all the differential terms. Then I solved for h(t+dt). Did the same for the second equation.

Comment: I am assuming the algebra is correct.  Another issue is that there is more than one discrete approximation - e.g., forward difference, backwards difference, and central difference.  These may behave differently in terms of stability and accuracy at difference time and space grid settings.

Comment: There are plenty of discretisations as Craig says. Yours looks correct at first glance. The trick is to pick an appropriate value of $\Delta t$ so your solutions don't blow up. Generally something $\Delta t<(\Delta x)^2$ is sufficient as long as no variables get too large. Another approach is to only discretise the spatial variables and write 2 first order ODE's in time for each grid point, and solve with any old ODE solver.